# How do I simplify this cmake file?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt5

I have this CMakeLists.txt.
From the pattern it seems there is a better and cleaner way to do it.

```
QT5_WRAP_CPP(windowui_moc ../../include/QtDisplay/WindowUI.hpp)
QT5_WRAP_CPP(mainwindow_moc ../../include/QtDisplay/MainWindow.hpp)
QT5_WRAP_CPP(editor_moc ../../include/QtDisplay/SpiderEditor.hpp)
QT5_WRAP_CPP(output_moc ../../include/QtDisplay/OutputPane.hpp)

add_library(Display WindowUI.cpp MainWindow.cpp SpiderEditor.cpp OutputPane.cpp
                    ${windowui_moc} ${mainwindow_moc} ${editor_moc} ${output_moc})

qt5_use_modules(Display Widgets Core)
```

I don't know much about the conventions used in cmake, so I can not look up what the 'solution' is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you looking for something like this:

```
set (Display_src
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/WindowUI.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/MainWindow.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/SpiderEditor.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/OutputPane.cpp
)

set (Display_hdr
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../include/QtDisplay/WindowUI.hpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../include/QtDisplay/MainWindow.hpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../include/QtDisplay/SpiderEditor.hpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../include/QtDisplay/OutputPane.hpp
)

qt5_wrap_cpp (Display_hdr_moc ${Display_hdr})

add_library (Display 
    ${Display_src}
    ${Display_hdr_moc}
)

# For Qt 5.2+
target_link_libraries (Display Qt5::Widgets)    
# For Qt 5.1.
# qt5_use_modules(Display Widgets Core)
```

Comment: I think so.
Can the Display_hdr set be constructed automatically from the source ?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned no. It can be achieved but in my opinion it is wrong way. You not always has pairs of source and header, sometimes you have single source, sometimes you have different names of source and header etc.

Comment: Don't use qt5_use_modules unless you're using Qt 5.1 (the documentation tells you this).

Comment: @steveire, Thanks for topical advice, it's surprise for me!

Comment: @Gluttton you don't need to be explicit about linking to Qt5::Core either. You only need to specify the 'leaf' dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the automoc feature of CMake like this:

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

add_library(Display MainWindow.cpp SpiderEditor.cpp OutputPane.cpp)

qt5_use_modules(Display Widgets Core)
```

Comment: That requires the header files to be in the same directory.

Comment: Ok, in this case add `set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)`. Which will add the current build directory as include directory. This is where where your generated moc files will be. I've updated the code in my answer.

Comment: CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR is for when your headers are in the build dir, like when they are auto generated.